# Programmatically save an MHT without dialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, mhtml

Is it possible to save a file of any type bypassing the 'save as' dialog? using the WebBrowser Class

```
WebBrowser.ShowSaveAsDialog();
```

Is the loaded content in a WebBrowser control serializable so it can be saved and retrieved (for redisplay)?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have full access to the DOM and can therefore read any contents that the WebBrowser is displaying the answer **must be yes**.

- Using the tree of DOM nodes read the contents of the WebBrowser into the C# world
- Write to the file using normal .NET file access

**However if you just wish to download a webpage and save it to disk there are better ways then using the WebBrowser control, have a look at the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class**

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, but I'm just going to update with a possible alternative.

Please take a look in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/MhtBuilder.aspx).